# SvelteKit how to return value only if variable is defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How i can return `gamble: gambleData` value only when `_gambleData` is defined cause now im getting

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'totalPlayers')

There is my code

```
export const load = async ({ locals }) => {
    let _gambleData;
    const gambleRef = collection(firestore, 'gambles');
    const gambleQuery = query(gambleRef, orderBy('date', 'desc'), limit(1));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(gambleQuery, (gambleSnapshot) => {
        gambleSnapshot.forEach((gambleDoc) => {
            _gambleData = gambleDoc.data();
        });
    });

    let gambleData;

    if (_gambleData != undefined) {
        gambleData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_gambleData));
    } else {
        console.error('error: gamble data is undefined');
    }

    return {
        user: locals.user,
        gamble: gambleData
    };
};
```

Document that im trying to snapshot:
[document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLPkT.png)

I tried `if()` inside return but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: That error message doesn't seem related to any of the code you show here.  Also it's not at all clear why you stringify then parse `_gambleData`.  That probably isn't what you want to do with the data in the document snapshot, especially if it contains data like timestamps.  Also it's kind of hard to imagine what this code is going to do because we can't see the document you're reading.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: i had issue before where without JSON.parse and stringify i couldn't acces like `gamble.date` BTW. added docuemnt png

Comment: Well, you definitely shouldn't have to stringify and parse just to get at document data.  The problem you had before should probably be resolved first.  You should also look into the code that causes the error message, because it's not what you're showing here.  It's really difficult to figure out what the problem is with what you have now.

Comment: Ok so im doing `console.log(gambleData)` without `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` and if document updates I see in console my document but written 11times idk why that's kinda weird I think im supposed to get only one cause i have query with `limit(1)` & issue with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'totalPlayers')` is probably cause im trying to return `gamble: gambleData' before document is updated so i don't have this document snapshot